# Sorting a dictionary by average of list in value

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the keys are names and the values are lists of up to 3 integers (these are the scores of the named people):

```
classScores={
    'Bob':[1, 6, 3],
    'Jim':[6, 10, 3],
    'Fred':[0, 2]
}
```

I need to print it sorted by the average of the scores (highest first).  I have created a working code to do this:

```
classAverages={}
for student in classScores:
    classAverages[student]=sum(classScores[student])/len(classScores[student])
for student in sorted(classAverages, key=classAverages.get, reverse=True):
    print(student, "Average:", sum(classScores[student])/len(classScores[student]))
```

However, I feel this is inefficient as it uses 2 `for` loops so has to go through every student twice.  I am therefore looking for suggestions that incorporate the sorting into the 2nd loop (presumably into its sorted function).

UPDATE: I've gone with a lambda, but I have defined it before the `for` loop so that I can also use it to print the averages:

```
classAverages=lambda student: sum(classScores[student]) / len(classScores[student])
for student in sorted(classScores, key=classAverages, reverse=True):
    print(student, "Average:", classAverages(student))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the average per student in the `key` function:

```
for student in sorted(classScores, key=lambda k: sum(classScores[k]) / len(classScores[k]), reverse=True):
```

Using two loops is only marginally less efficient however; you only increased the fixed cost per student to determine the order. You missed an opportunity to re-use that average in your second loop when *displaying* the averages:

```
classAverages={}
for student in classScores:
    classAverages[student] = sum(classScores[student]) / len(classScores[student])

for student in sorted(classAverages, key=classAverages.get, reverse=True):
    print(student, "Average:", classAverages[student])
```

You could loop over the dictionary items in a generator expression to calculate the averages, sort on those averages, and then display the calculated average all in one operation:

```
student_averages = ((sum(scores) / len(scores), s) for s, scores in classScores.items())

for average, student in sorted(student_averages, reverse=True):
    print(student, "Average:", average)
```

The generator produces the data in `(average, student)` pairs to ease sorting (we now don't need a `key` to pick out the second value).

Comment: Thanks! Using lambda worked (with the addition of `reverse=True`). And I never thought of using re-using the classAverages data!

Comment: "memoizing" `classAverages.get` would be another way to avoid recalculating, while maintaining the original approach, right?

Comment: @alexis: right. You could just sort `classAverages.items()` (with `lambda pair: pair[1]`, or `operator.itemgetter(1)` as the key function). You then have a sorted sequence of `student, average` tuples.

Comment: @DanielO'Toole The generator solution looks nicer than your lambda and is more efficient